# styled links only work sometimes or only after opening/closing links in a specific order

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

http://www.tweeturrep.com.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com/index.html

for some reason when i added style to the nav bar at the top, the links started to only work sometimes. for example, u can't click to enter your zip code until u open and close the votes modal. also if u mouseover the videos link it'll change to the pointer then back and u can't click. idk whats going on but i think it's something to do with bootstrap stuff

```
<div class="content" position="absolute">
<table position="absolute">
  <tr>
    <td class="navOPtion">
    <img class ="navImage" src="navicon.png">
    </td>
    <td class="navOPtion" id="hideNav5">
    <a style="color:white" href="index.html" id="home">home</a>
    </td>
    <td class="navOPtion" id="hideNav1">
    <a style="color:white" href="videos.html" id="videos" >videos</a>
    </td>
    <td class="navOPtion" id="hideNav">
    <a style="color:white" href="resume.html" target="blank" id="resume">resume</a>
    </td>
    <td class="navOPtion" id="hideNav2">
    <a style="color:white" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal1">
        about
      </a>
    </td>
    <td class="navOPtion" id="hideNav3">
    <a style="color:white" href="blog.html">blog</a>
    </td>
    <td class="navOPtion" id="hideNav4">
      <a  style="color:white" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
        votes
      </a>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="title" colspan="7">
      tweetUrRep
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="search" colspan="7">
      <form  id="find_overlords" align="center">
        <form action="" id="find_overlords" type="post">
          <input type="text" id="user_Zip" name="zip" placeholder="Zip code" style="width:225px; height:75px; 
          font-size:20pt" class="input33"></input>
          <input type="image" src="search-13-128.png" name="saveForm"     class="smallSearchIcon" id="saveForm" >
          <br>
          <input type="image" src="search-13-128.png" name="saveForm"     class="searchIcon" id="saveForm" >
      </form>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

the css:

```
table{
    position:static;
    margin:auto auto auto auto;
    color:white;
    width:100%;
}
  .navImage {
    height: 50px;
    width: 75px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.navOPtion{
    width:10%;
}

#hideNav{
    display:none;
    font-size: 30px;
}

#hideNav2{
    display:none;
    font-size: 30px;
}

#hideNav3{
    display:none;
    font-size: 30px;
}

#hideNav4{
    display:none;
    font-size: 30px;
    color:white;
}

#hideNav5{
display:none;
font-size: 30px;
color:white;
}

#hideNav1{
display:none;
font-size: 30px;
color:white;
}
```

the javascript to display the hideNavs:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.navImage').click(function(){
    $('#hideNav').slideToggle('fast');
    $('#hideNav1').slideToggle('fast');
    $('#hideNav2').slideToggle('fast');
    $('#hideNav3').slideToggle('fast');
    $('#hideNav4').slideToggle('fast');
    $('#hideNav5').slideToggle('fast');
  });
});
```

Comment: Can you please provide a code example in the question and improve grammar and spelling to improve readability?

Comment: Your modals are not hidden. You can investigate why, or just add in document ready function `$('.modal.fade').hide();` (tested, works).